# Python 3. Проблема с областью видимости в декораторе от pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, область-видимости, декоратор

Для вопроса я упростил кусок кода. В общем, когда я присылаю в чат боту "/play" срабатывает `@message_handler()`, который запускает функцию `send_string(m_id)`, принимающая ID собеседника. Далее функция `send_string(m_id)` отправляет сообщение с **random_num** с прикрепленным **маркапом** (*InlineKeyboardButton*). Ожидаем нажатие маркапа. Как только собеседник нажал на маркап срабатывает `@callback_query_handler()`, после которого бот отправляет сообщение в чат с тем же `random_num`. Затем происходит рекурсия обратно на `send_string(m_id)`.

```
def send_string(m_id):
    random_num = random.randint(10,99)
    bot.send_message(m_id, f"some text - {str(random_num)}", reply_markup = get_markup())

    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def test_callback(message):
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, str(random_num))
        send_string(message.from_user.id)

@bot.message_handler(commands = ["play"])
def get_message(message):
    send_string(message.from_user.id)
```

Проблема в том, что хоть и при каждом изменении `random_num`, его первоначальное значение остается таким же, каким было в первый раз:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно выглядеть вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут, я уверен, проблема с областью видимости, которая "запуталась" из-за декоратора. Я перепробовал разные комбинации с `nonlocal`, `global`, но это ни к чему не привело. Прошу вас помочь, уже несколько дней не могу сдвинуться с этой проблемы.

Comment: Добрый день. Времени прошло много. Тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой, удалось Вам её решить?